# CustomError and ConnectionStrings

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an Error.aspx page to handle any Application_Error.

But there is one that I can't catch : When the site can't connect to the DB specified with the connectionstrings, Application_Error is called (in global.asax) but I don't reach Error.aspx even if there is no DB connection needed to display it. Instead, I have the standard ASP red message saying that there was an application Error on custom error page.

Any Idea to catch this error type ?

Comment: seems you are writing error message in database first and then redirecting to Error.aspx

Comment: @AnupamSingh : Not at all. There is absolutely no DB connection to show the Error.aspx page or to handle error.

Comment: For errors of this type, you can use a static HTML error page.

Comment: @Joe : Thanks, it already is. It doesn't rely on a .master. It's just a page to show a message saying "there was an error".

Comment: @SeyoS - By a static page, I mean a page with an .htm or .html extension, not an .aspx page.

Comment: @Joe : I need to do some things on the background (not BDD connection)